# Laravel PSR-4 : No hint path defined for [User]

Tags: php, laravel-4, psr-4

I am trying to make a view on my package, and this is my code:

```
 View::make("User::login");
```

But I get this error: `No hint path defined for [User].`

My structure is like this:

```
app
├──config
├──database
├── modules
            └── Core
                    └── User
                            ├──Controllers
                            ├──models
                            └──views
                                    └──login.blade.php
                            ├── lang
                            ├── migrations
                            └── routes.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The view *namespaces* actually have nothing to do with PSR-4. You also have to add view directories manually. You can either do that by adding it to the `paths` array in `config/view.php` or by registering it somewhere else (preferably in a service provider)

```
View::addLocation('/path/to/views');
```

To come back to your actual question, you can register view namespaces like this:

```
View::addNamespace('User', '/path/to/views');
```

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved my problem.
it was my fault, it should be :

```
 View::make("Core/User::login");
```

thanks.

Comment: You don't had to register the namespace by `View::addNamespace()`?